# How can I call the Preferences with the new values?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I use some CheckBoxPreferences, but they are not indepentent. That means, wenn I change one CheckBoxPreference, others are fixed. I use the following code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
       Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
       prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); 
   } 

   @Override 
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs, String key) {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
      if ((key.equals("A")) & (key.equals("B"))) {
          editor.putBoolean("C", true);
          editor.commit();
      }
   }
}
```

After this the CheckBoxPreference "C" has a new value, but I can't see it. How can I update the screen with the new values?

Answer (score 0):

By using a subclass of PreferenceActivity you do not have to handle the updating of the preferences UI. You define the preferences in the resource file loaded by addPreferencesFromResource() and the Activity will be rendered accordingly. Changes will be persisted automatically and should be visible immediately. You do not have to register your preferences Activity as a SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

When onSharedPreferenceChanged() is called the new value is already saved to the preferences.

This notification is for other Activities than the subclasses of PreferenceActivity. To know how to access the saved preferences you need to look at the file in res/xml/settings.xml it should contain android:key attributes. The attribute values give you the key to the preference.

You can retrieve the value via the following:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(aContext).getString(key, "");
```